# Define column position in Ui grid Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

here's how i defined one of my col in Ui grid :

```
getDeviceTypeList = function () {
        BaseInfoService.getDeviceTypeList().then(function (data) {
            debugger;
            $scope.deviceTypeList = data;

            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push(

                        {
                            headerCellTemplate: '<div>{{"common.DeviceType"|translate}}</div>',
                            cellTemplate: '<div>{{getExternalScopes().deviceTypeFormatter(row.entity.DeviceTypeCode)}}</div>',
                            field: 'DeviceTypeCode',
                            enableCellEdit: true,
                            editType: 'dropdown',
                            editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.deviceTypeList,
                            editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
                            editDropdownIdLabel: 'SubCode',
                            editDropdownValueLabel: 'ParamDesc',
                            editModelField: 'DeviceTypeCode'
                        }
                );

        })
    }
```

but other col defined like :

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {

        columnDefs: [
       {
       name:"soheil"},
      { name: 'توضیحات', field: 'Command', headerCellTemplate: '<div>{{"common.Comment"|translate}}</div>', editModelField: 'Command' },
      { name: 'تعداد', field: 'NeededDeviceNumber', headerCellTemplate: '<div>{{"common.NeededDeviceNumber"|translate}}</div>', type: 'number', editModelField: 'NeededDeviceNumber' },

      //{ name: 'نوع وسایل', field: 'DeviceType', headerCellTemplate: '<div>{{"common.DeviceType"|translate}}</div>', cellTemplate: '<select ng-model="neededDiviceViewModel.templateCode" ng-options="item.SubCode as item.ParamDesc for item in dastourKarViewModelList"><option value="" style="display:none" selected="selected">انتخاب</option></select>' }
        ],
    }
```

how can i defined custom position for column ? Now It's like :
1 3 5 2 4

and that's not what i want , Like : 1 2 3 4

Any Idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more clear about what positions for columns you want? Also are you dynamically adding new columns to the grid?

Comment: assume the column should be like this : col1 col2 dynamic-col col3 but now it's like : dynamic-col col1 col2 col 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `splice` function to insert new column definitions at the correct place

```
$scope.columns.splice(1, 0, { field: 'company', enableSorting: false });
```

Above code adds a new column at the second position. See the example from the uioo-grid [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/113_adding_and_removing_columns)

UPDATE: For your this requirement "assume the column should be like this : col1 col2 dynamic-col col3 but now it's like : dynamic-col col1 col2 col 3" you need to use following code

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.splice(2, 0, { headerCellTemplate: '<div>{{"common.DeviceType"|translate}}</div>',
    cellTemplate: '<div>{{getExternalScopes().deviceTypeFormatter(row.entity.DeviceTypeCode)}}</div>',
    field: 'DeviceTypeCode',
    enableCellEdit: true,
    editType: 'dropdown',
    editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.deviceTypeList,
    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
    editDropdownIdLabel: 'SubCode',
    editDropdownValueLabel: 'ParamDesc',
    editModelField: 'DeviceTypeCode'
});
```

Comment: that's ok , but i can't move static column ?

Comment: columDef is just a JS array. Arrange it anyway you want and the columns will show up accordingly. I'm not sure what else you are expecting. You are in control of creating the order in which the columns should display.

Answer (score 1):

columnDef is an array and you need to just push the columns in same sequence in which you want to show. For push dynamically columns, you need to handle these cases through data and code.

Comment: so you mean it's not possible ?

Comment: Yes.. you just need to set the array according to your requirements.. There is no another way to change the sequence..

Comment: In above answer, just changing the array positions not anything else.. there are many ways in code you can change the array but there is no option where you can set the showing sequence.. if you know then please share with me..